# In angular2, how to call a function inside an element without mouse event?

Tags: function, angular

Below is part of code in parent component, I already get the enable value from eventEmitter in its child component, which is enable=true.

```
<img src="{{currentImg}}" alt="Play Image not found" (click)="onMouseClick()">
<pause-button (isPauseBtnClicked)="enable = $event"></pause-button>
status is: {{enable}}
```

Then how can I assign a value for currentImg="someImg.png" after it listened the eventEmitter(enable=true)? Should I write a function? if so, how can I call that function in img tag without any mouse event?

I konw with mouse click event, things becomes easier, currentImg can be assign a value inside function.

```
onMouseClick() {
        this.currentImg = this.clickedImg;
    }
```

Comment: Through eventEmitter this can be achieved.

Comment: isPauseBtnClicked is an eventEmitter. So when you child component say `pause-button` fires it, isPauseBtnClicked will be fired of parentComponent. There you can write your stuff.

Comment: What do you actually try to accomplish? Where does `clicked Image` come from, where should it be assigned to and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look I don't know what you want to achieve. But writing this answer by thinking that you want to go with `EventEmitter` way without calling any `mouseevent`.

**Note: Your expectation might be different. But It might help you out. If doesn't, kindly use it as a reference. I might have understood something completely different but purpose is not to guide you in wrong way**

```
<img src="{{currentImg}}" alt="Play Image not found" (click)="onMouseClick()">
<pause-button (isPauseBtnClicked)="fire($event)"></pause-button><br>
status is: {{enable}}<br>   // haven't played with status
{{currentImg}}
```

**boot.ts**

```
fire(arg) {
          console.log('test start');
          //this.animate.subscribe((value) => { this.name = value; });
          this.currentImg=arg;
          console.log(arg);
      }
```

**[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T67GYnXy8igIe8RtUaNq?p=preview)**

---

**PasueButton.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'pause-button ',  
template: `
________________________________________________________
      <br>
      I'm child 
      <br>
      <img src="img path" (click)="clickMe()"/>
      <= click the img
      <br>
_____________________________________________________
   `
, 
})

export class PasueButton implements OnInit {
      @Output() isPauseBtnClicked: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

       constructor() {
          console.log('Constructor called');
       }

        ngOnInit() {
           console.log('onit strat');
        }

       clickMe()
       {
            this.isPauseBtnClicked.next('child Img path is copied');
       }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for make you confused. I mean after the parent component listened a mouse event and get eventEmitter(enable=true) from child component. Then how can it trigger parent <img> tag to change value in src {{currentImg}} and get a new image. Please ignore the click event on <img> tag.

Comment: But if `img` tag is in parent and if you want to change parent then why do u want to go into child ?

Comment: I need mouse click event on another image in child, and with that image clicked, I'd like to change the src of image in parent. Anyway, I get some idea from your code, thanks. When it was done, I'll upload my code in plunker.

Comment: Yup that is what I have done. Let me show you how to do it.

Comment: Now you can check my answer

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: If its satisfied your answer, u should mark it as an answer. So other users can refer to it.

Comment: OK. I marked. And do you know how to add more features on it? Right now if click the image in child, it can make the parent image change. Besides that, I hope to click the image in parent, make the image change in child?